# B2B customers with Magento Open source

Tags: magento2, b2b, magento2-b2b, opensource

we want to make use of the Magento Open source version. Is there any community extension to handle B2B customers and quotes?
I only want to use Magento as Backend/Admin software without any shop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/b2b/bk-b2b.html

and here is the extesnion which can be handy for you

**paid**

https://amasty.com/b2b-ecommerce-suite-for-magento-2.html

**free**

https://github.com/magearray/magento2-wholesale-b2b

https://github.com/hi-iwd/b2b

https://github.com/fruitcake/magento2-b2b-essentials

hope this helps

Comment: In the first link i see that it is official b2b extension is for commerce version only. Am i right that i have to search for a community extension to do that?

Comment: can i find the free extensions in the marketplace?

Comment: first link you mean the document that i have shared?

Comment: no thats why i have shared some free extension that are available on github

Comment: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/b2b/bk-b2b.html i only want to use the free version of magento or is Magento Commerce also free?

Comment: @ChristophBraun that first link was only for the infromation

Comment: All your links are connected to a running Shop with products, but i only searching for the Admin tool to handle my own custom products which cannot connect to a catalog. I dont know if Magento is the correct software for this use-case